# how can I import multiple CSS files conditionally based on this.state data in react native

Tags: css, react-native

I need to import multiple css files conditionally in react native project like

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
if(this.state.language = "he"){
  import styles from "./he";
}else{
  import styles from "./en";
}
```

But it's not working.  I need to add 2 different CSS for LTR and RTL based on language.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you explain what is wrong? (Share un-/expected behavior or an error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like the following code

```
import heStyles from "./he";
import enStyles from "./en";

const styles = this.state.language = "he" ? heStyles : enStyles;
```

Comment: can I get this.state.language before import statement ?

Comment: state belongs to your class component, you cant get it before import

Comment: if you store language in asyncstorage, you could create separate style file, import those style file then export specic style based on language get from asyncstorage

Comment: I can put that asyncstorage condition here as well right?

Comment: is there any example available for export specific style based on language get from asyncstorage

Comment: @MukeshKumarSharma yes, you can

Comment: import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  AsyncStorage,

} from "react-native";
import heStyles from "./he";
import enStyles from "./en";


var  language = AsyncStorage.getItem('language');
alert(JSON.stringify(language));
const Styles = language = "language" ? heStyles : enStyles;
export default Styles;



it this correct? I am always getting else part (enStyles).

Comment: what is the value of language, why are you comparing language to "language", and you need to use === (or ==) to compare two values instead of =

Comment: Thanks for the last comment, I have figured out the issue, But still I am not able to get value from of language from Asyncstorage. 
var language = AsyncStorage.getItem('language');

Comment: Did you store it in AsyncStorage?

Comment: yes I did ...and when alert using await it show me the value of language. Basically I need t export component after getting value of language from asyncstorage but value is getting after export so not able to put condition based on asycstorage language.